# R - Splitting dataframe into vectors and passing all of them as different arguments to same function

Tags: r

I have a function that takes as many "data vector" inputs as desired, and performs operations on all of them together. So following works:

```
myFunction( df[,1], df[,2], df[,3], ..up to the number of columns.. )
```

I would like to split a data frame (or matrix) into different column vectors and supply all of them as different inputs (basically example above without having to write the each column one by one)

I have already tried to following:

```
myFunction( split( df, col(df) ) )
```

and this doesn't work because the function I am trying to use does not accept list of inputs, it expects each of them to be a different argument.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `do.call(myFunction, df)` ?

Comment: It might be easier to pass the full `df`, and then operate on the columns inside `myFunction` with `lapply`/`sapply`.

Comment: @digEmAll it does not recognize which input it should match the elements of do.call. `argument "x" is missing, with no default`

Comment: @MauritsEvers I would have to go and modify the source file (I didnt write the function), so I thought maybe there is a neater way out there

Comment: @digEmAll figured it out, do.call was a very good suggestion thank you. I just had to rename the first element of the list as 'x', it works that way

Comment: Try `do.call(myfunction, unname(as.list(df)))` to remove the names.

Comment: it works at the moment, as long as I name any element in the list as "x", it recognizes the rest. I guess I should write it all together as an answer so that post is closed. Thanks a lot everyone, this saved me a lot of ugly copy pastes :)

Comment: By the way, note that `df[, 1]` is not a single column data frame.  It is a vector.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck noted! (and edited the title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example of what is suggested in the comments:

```
argumentList <- split(df, col(df)) # create a list of arguments
names(argumentList)[1] <- "x" # name at least one of the inputs for the default value x 
argumentList["na.rm"] <- TRUE # add any other arguments needed
do.call( myFunction, argumentList )
```

Comment: Demonstrate this with a simple reproducible numeric example to reveal it clearly.

Comment: `exampleFunction <- function(x,...){ arguments <- list(...); result<-sum(x); for(i in 1:length(arguments){result <- result+sum(arguments[i])^i } ) }`

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be ambiguous a little. That said, the following covers the things mentioned in the question to a great extent.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(rep(rnorm(10),5)), ncol=5, byrow=TRUE))
df
sum(df[,1], df[,2], df[,3], df[,4], df[,5])      # 6.610139
sum(unlist(lapply(as.matrix(1:ncol(df)), function(i) {df[,i] }))) # 6.610139
```

Comment: That only works because how inputs are separated is not important for sum(), but would cause a problem for nonlinear operations. because unlist combines everything into one large vector.